# How to make not show 'As low as $'? - Magento2

Tags: magento2

I just update a product's price but on front-end page, the old price show up like 'as low as $'

I don't want to show old price as the way Why this feature is needed? How to make it not show?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @NathanToombs No :( Please update when you find solution

Answer (score 1):

So the solution is to modify the template in `Magento\Catalog\view\base\templates\product\view\final_price.phtml` and remove these lines from that template

```
<?php if ($block->showMinimalPrice()): ?>
    <?php if ($block->getUseLinkForAsLowAs()):?>
        <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getSaleableItem()->getProductUrl(); ?>" class="minimal-price-link">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmountMinimal(); ?>
        </a>
    <?php else:?>
        <span class="minimal-price-link">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmountMinimal(); ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You will, of course, want to override that template in your own theme. There may be another solution that involves getting `$block->showMinimalPrice()` to evaluate to false but I didn't have the time to figure that out and this is a workable solution for modifying a theme.

Answer (score -1):

Normally you just need to reindex the site.. the system will update and the incorrect price will disappear.

./bin/magento indexer:reindex